# Why is it so complicated in Stack Overflow to subscribe to a subject?

Tags: feature-request, user-experience

I often have opened interesting pages like
https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ubuntu
and I would like to subscribe to those pages to get E-Mails if there are any news.

Why does Stack Overflow not offer a "favorite star" like [image]
to subscribe to pagers with just one click?

I'd like to understand this usability decision.

Comment: You can set up an RSS feed apparently. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3403/rss-feed-of-your-favorite-tags. I don't think there's any email alerting available at all though.

Comment: @MartinSmith on the filter setup you can also select to send an email: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224557/158100

Comment: @rene thanks. I was completely unaware that functionality existed.

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks a lot for your anwer; on a hidden stackoverflow place I was able to subscribe to some topics and I get those news by a daily E-Mail. RSS is annoying because I have to poll for news. E-Mails are great because news get automatically to my inbox - and the are my ToDo-List :-)

Comment: Hi rene, thanks for this Link!, it's exactly what I ask for: I don't understand that Stackoverflow does not offer to automatically create a filter for users by a single click :-)

Comment: Hi rene, because stackoverflow is a place with an usually great usability we can learn from, I thought that there is an interesting decision to not support "add favorite" to websites.

Answer (score 10):

It is pretty simple. When I hover my mouse over a tag, I get the following dialog:

[image: hover over a tag...]

Note the "subscribe" and "rss" links in the top right that I circled. When I click "subscribe" it sends an email confirmation that will subscribe me to daily emails for that tag. (Click it again to unsubscribe.) Clicking the "rss" link takes you to the URL you need to add posts in the tag to the RSS reader of your choosing.

Comment: Without the diamond, you still rock. :) +1.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer and your Hint!, but it does not solve the problem I have asked for: I'd often like to a URL, e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/ubuntu

But your hint is a nice start: It would be great if Stackoverflow would not immediately create a subscription E-Mail but open the default Filter / Subscription page with pre-filled values as a subscription-proposal so that we could modify the Site- and Tag-Filter property :-)